# execv arguments error - "expected char * const* but argument is of type const char *"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, exec

I have a function whose argument is `const char *array[]`

`array[0]` is the path, the rest are the arguments and it ends with `NULL`.

However, if I try to do `execv(array[0], array)` I get `expected char * const* but argument is of type const char *`

How do I go about this, and what is the difference between `char * const*` and `const char *`?

```
void start(const char *array[]) {
    execv(array[0], array);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a few `*` too much. Did that happen during copying or do you really have that `***` stuff?

Comment: Please show a complete example how you call that function. How do you define and initialize your array?

Comment: yes sorry the *'s were a mistake fixed it now.

Comment: i added the function, and how I implemented execv. But this is giving an error and I dont know why

Comment: Remove `const` from your parameter list.

Comment: thats part of the question I cannot remove the argument of the function. I have to change the function content

Comment: OK, then you can update the question with the code you added to provide proper parameters. You will need to copy the array.

Comment: BTW: The error message does not seem to be copied correctly. The expected parameter type matches second parameter. But you do not provide `const char*` for that parameter. You provide `const char **`

Comment: The error im gettting is correct.

Comment: I just want to know what I have to do in the function body instead of execv(array[0], array). I want to know how to implement execv inside the start function

Comment: I get different error: `note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’`

Comment: As I mentioned you need to copy that array. Copy the strings into an array that matches the expected type: `char *my_array[]; ` instead of `const char *array[]`. BTW: You could also try to use casts to get rid of `const´ but that is normally not the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

First, the error message is not copied correctly. If I run your code in GCC it shows this message instead (note the final `*`):

`note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘const char **’`

which makes more sense as the message you show in the question, does not match the code you show. There is a mismatch in level or indirection.

That said, let's look at this part:

> and what is the difference between `char * const*` and `const char *`?

Actually it is

> and what is the difference between `char * const*` and `const char **`?

The first is a pointer to a const pointer to a `char`. The `char` that is pointed to is not const and might in theory be changed by `execv`.

The latter is a pointer to a pointer to a const `char`. This means, the `char` that is pointed to mustn't be modified. It might be some read-only string literal in ROM. If you pass such a pointer to a function that will try to modify it, it will fail in one way or the other. Therefore you are not allowed to pass a "pointer to const" to a function that does not expect it to be const.
That is what the compiler is telling you.

Now, how can you get rid of that warning...
To silence your compiler you could try to use some cast and cheat about real nature of that parameter.
In the end the problem will stay the same. A function trying to modify your read-only memory will not be working properly.

Instead you need to make a copy of your data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void start(const char *array[]) {
    int i = 0;

    // determine number of strings (including NULL)
    while (array[i++] != NULL) ;

    // Create an array able to hold pointers to copys
    char *my_array[i];

    // Copy strings into non-const memory 
    i = 0;
    do 
        my_array[i] = array[i] ? strdup(array[i]) : NULL;
    while (array[i++] != NULL);
    
    execv(my_array[0], my_array);

    // Free the memory for the copied strings
    i = 0;
    do 
        free(my_array[i]);
    while (array[i++] != NULL);

}

int main(void)
{
    const char *argv[] = {"ls", "ls", NULL};
    
    start(argv);
    
    return 0;
}
```